# PHP: String won't insert into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My string field won't insert into my database.

(The columns follower_username and following_username they are VARCHAR(200) don't insert )
The: follower and following column values insert work.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `follow` (`follower`, `following`, `follower_username`, `following_username`) VALUES ('".$userid."', '".$get_user_id."', '".$username."', '".$get_user."')");
```

Strings:

```
$get_user = mysql_real_escape_string($row['username']);
$get_user_id = (int)mysql_real_escape_string($row['id']);
$userid = (int)mysql_real_escape_string($user_data['id']);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($user_data['username']);
```

I have no idea what to do, whether it is the PHP or the database itself :S

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you sure that the strings get assigned? Which variables don't get inserted? What happens if you `echo` them on their own? Do the correct values display?

Comment: I suppose you've read about mysql_query() in a blog article or something like that. Just head to the [manual page](http://php.net/mysql_query), scroll down the "do not use this extension" warning and check the examples provided; they both provide details on how to do error checking.

Comment: Is there any more code? Specifically where your getting the user_data array from?

Comment: The arrays work if I echo them, and they work in other queries, which is odd..

Comment: Either you're looping through rows (which is not posted in your code) or you meant to use `$get_user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);` etc, but it's hard to say without seeing full code, knowing where `$row` and `$user_data` are coming from.

Comment: I think follower and following are should be integer

Comment: Also make sure you're connected to your DB and the columns do in fact exist.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I copied and pasted the names over and it didn't work

Comment: You mean what I posted above? `$get_user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);` ? @Billy_2lgit_2qt

Comment: No, about the columns existing or not.

Comment: I'd need to see full code, there are too many factors at play, as well as knowing what your table structure is. @Billy_2lgit_2qt

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO follow (`follower`, `following`, `follower_username`, `following_username`) VALUES ('".$userid."', '".$get_user_id."', '".$username."', '".$get_user."')");
```

don't use single quotes around table name.

Answer (score 1):

You could try echoing the mysql statement just before the mysql_query, i.e.

```
echo "INSERT INTO `follow` (`follower`, `following`, `follower_username`, `following_username`) VALUES ('".$userid."', '".$get_user_id."', '".$username."', '".$get_user."')";
```

and check if the string is what you expected it to be. If it is what you expected, try manually copying the string and pasting it into the mysql console and see if any errors occur.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [`mysql_error`](http://pk1.php.net/mysql_error) to your statement to find out what error is it so you can fix it:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `follow` (`follower`, `following`, `follower_username`,
`following_username`) VALUES ('".$userid."', '".$get_user_id."', '".$username."',   
'".$get_user."')") or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

For debug and simple work I recommended you store SQL query in variable.

```
$query  = "INSERT INTO `follow` (`follower`, `following`, `follower_username`, `following_username`) VALUES ('".$userid."', '".$get_user_id."', '".$username."', '".$get_user."')";
echo "DEBUG:".$query;
mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
 $objQuery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `follow` (`follower`, `following`, `follower_username`,
    `following_username`) VALUES ($userid, $get_user_id, '".$username."',   
    '".$get_user."')") or die (mysql_error());

if(!$objQuery){
 echo "something went wrong!";
}
```

Comment: @Billy_2lgit_2qt : can you try this?

Comment: Do read my comments that have been given under your original question. @Billy_2lgit_2qt

Comment: @Billy_2lgit_2qt : i have updated my answer. can you try again? also check  Fred -ii- comments( check db connection)